# Change text on swipe

Tags: ios

I am creating a text jokes app what i need is i want the UITextView in swipe form like when i swipe the first joke after a gap another UITextview comes in with another joke  , so far what i have done is i have manually created the UITextView ( like if there is 10 jokes then 10 uitextview ) and added them in a scroll but that is taking too much time in viewdidload method and the app takes 6,7 second to load ... 
if you have anyother idea please do let me know

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrresult.count; i++) {




    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollmain.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollmain.frame.size;

    // UITextView *subview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((frame.origin.x)+40,(frame.origin.y)+10, 230, 120)];
    // UITextView *subview2 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((frame.origin.x)+40,(frame.origin.y)+160,230, 120)];

    UITextView *subview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((frame.origin.x)+40,(frame.origin.y)+10, 230, 120)];
    UITextView *subview2 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((frame.origin.x)+40,(frame.origin.y)+160,230, 120)];


    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG_text.png"]];
    subview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [subview setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [subview2 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

    subview.layer.cornerRadius = 10 ;
    subview2.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    NSString *p = [duaobj2 dua_arabic];
    NSString *b = [duaobj2 eng_trans];

    subview.text = p;
    subview2.text = b;

    [self.scrollmain addSubview:subview];
    [self.scrollmain addSubview:subview2];

    subview.editable = NO;
    subview2.editable = NO;

    subview.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    subview2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    subview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    scrollmain.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    CGRect frame1 = subview.frame;
    CGRect frame2 = subview2.frame;

    frame1.size.height = subview.contentSize.height;
    frame2.size.height = subview2.contentSize.height;

    subview.frame = frame1;
    subview2.frame = frame2;





}


self.scrollmain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollmain.frame.size.width * arrresult.count,self.scrollmain.frame.size.height);

scrollmain.pagingEnabled = TRUE;

scrollmain.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to load the subviews at the time of viewDidLoad.

You should delay this by using scrollView delegate methods.

You should create only 3 textviews at max. Current, previous and next.

On scrollViewDidScroll delegate method, you should wisely remove previously loaded textview and you should add new textview.

Comment: thanks a lot man ... atleast now i have a logic i'll try to implement